# Ayuda con insertar slide en vista cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-bake

En el trabajo tengo una aplicación de hace unos años, de una empresa que ya no existe, desarrollada en cakephp 1.3 , el cual estoy intentando aprender y razonar pero aún no me alcanza. El tema es que el php está ofuscado, y necesito modificar una vista , la misma tiene unos divs y paneles que logré comentar, y necesito insertarle un slider con unas imágenes.
Copio el código, lo extraño del caso son 2 cosas.
1) Directamente no se visualiza.
2) Cuando corro el slider por alguna razçon que desconozco no se visualizan las flechas laterales.

Agradeceré cualquier ayuda !
Gracias !

```html
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {  
   renderTexts();
   renderButtons(['entrar','volver']);
   // $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({
    // showArrows: true,
    // horizontalGutter: 30,
    // verticalGutter: 30
   // });
   // $('.panel').center();
   
   lockHelpPanel = false;
   close_alert_UI();
  });
 </script>

<div class="panel mid flyin">
    <div class="panel-content">
 <body style="padding:0px; margin:0px; background-color:#fff;font-family:helvetica, arial, verdana, sans-serif">
    <!-- #region Jssor Slider Begin -->
    <!-- Generator: Jssor Slider Maker -->
    <!-- Source: http://www.jssor.com -->
    <!-- This code works without jquery library. -->
    <script src="js/jssor.slider-22.0.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jssor_1_slider_init = function() {
            var jssor_1_SlideoTransitions = [
              [{b:0,d:600,y:-290,e:{y:27}}],
              [{b:0,d:1000,y:185},{b:1000,d:500,o:-1},{b:1500,d:500,o:1},{b:2000,d:1500,r:360},{b:3500,d:1000,rX:30},{b:4500,d:500,rX:-30},{b:5000,d:1000,rY:30},{b:6000,d:500,rY:-30},{b:6500,d:500,sX:1},{b:7000,d:500,sX:-1},{b:7500,d:500,sY:1},{b:8000,d:500,sY:-1},{b:8500,d:500,kX:30},{b:9000,d:500,kX:-30},{b:9500,d:500,kY:30},{b:10000,d:500,kY:-30},{b:10500,d:500,c:{x:87.50,t:-87.50}},{b:11000,d:500,c:{x:-87.50,t:87.50}}],
              [{b:0,d:600,x:410,e:{x:27}}],
              [{b:-1,d:1,o:-1},{b:0,d:600,o:1,e:{o:5}}],
              [{b:-1,d:1,c:{x:175.0,t:-175.0}},{b:0,d:800,c:{x:-175.0,t:175.0},e:{c:{x:7,t:7}}}],
              [{b:-1,d:1,o:-1},{b:0,d:600,x:-570,o:1,e:{x:6}}],
              [{b:-1,d:1,o:-1,r:-180},{b:0,d:800,o:1,r:180,e:{r:7}}],
              [{b:0,d:1000,y:80,e:{y:24}},{b:1000,d:1100,x:570,y:170,o:-1,r:30,sX:9,sY:9,e:{x:2,y:6,r:1,sX:5,sY:5}}],
              [{b:2000,d:600,rY:30}],
              [{b:0,d:500,x:-105},{b:500,d:500,x:230},{b:1000,d:500,y:-120},{b:1500,d:500,x:-70,y:120},{b:2600,d:500,y:-80},{b:3100,d:900,y:160,e:{y:24}}],
              [{b:0,d:1000,o:-0.4,rX:2,rY:1},{b:1000,d:1000,rY:1},{b:2000,d:1000,rX:-1},{b:3000,d:1000,rY:-1},{b:4000,d:1000,o:0.4,rX:-1,rY:-1}]
            ];
            var jssor_1_options = {
              $AutoPlay: true,
              $Idle: 2500,
              $CaptionSliderOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorCaptionSlideo$,
                $Transitions: jssor_1_SlideoTransitions,
                $Breaks: [
                  [{d:2000,b:1000}]
                ]
              },
              $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$
              },
              $BulletNavigatorOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$
              }
            };
            var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", jssor_1_options);
            };
    </script>
    <style>
        /* jssor slider bullet navigator skin 01 css */
        /*
        .jssorb01 div           (normal)
        .jssorb01 div:hover     (normal mouseover)
        .jssorb01 .av           (active)
        .jssorb01 .av:hover     (active mouseover)
        .jssorb01 .dn           (mousedown)
        */
        .jssorb01 {
            position: absolute;
        }
        .jssorb01 div, .jssorb01 div:hover, .jssorb01 .av {
            position: absolute;
            /* size of bullet elment */
            width: 12px;
            height: 12px;
            filter: alpha(opacity=70);
            opacity: .7;
            overflow: hidden;
            cursor: pointer;
            border: #000 1px solid;
        }
        .jssorb01 div { background-color: gray; }
        .jssorb01 div:hover, .jssorb01 .av:hover { background-color: #d3d3d3; }
        .jssorb01 .av { background-color: #fff; }
        .jssorb01 .dn, .jssorb01 .dn:hover { background-color: #555555; }

        /* jssor slider arrow navigator skin 02 css */
        /*
        .jssora02l                  (normal)
        .jssora02r                  (normal)
        .jssora02l:hover            (normal mouseover)
        .jssora02r:hover            (normal mouseover)
        .jssora02l.jssora02ldn      (mousedown)
        .jssora02r.jssora02rdn      (mousedown)
        .jssora02l.jssora02lds      (disabled)
        .jssora02r.jssora02rds      (disabled)
        */
        .jssora02l, .jssora02r {
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            /* size of arrow element */
            width: 55px;
            height: 55px;
            cursor: pointer;
            background: url('img/a02.png') no-repeat;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .jssora02l { background-position: -3px -33px; }
        .jssora02r { background-position: -63px -33px; }
        .jssora02l:hover { background-position: -123px -33px; }
        .jssora02r:hover { background-position: -183px -33px; }
        .jssora02l.jssora02ldn { background-position: -3px -33px; }
        .jssora02r.jssora02rdn { background-position: -63px -33px; }
        .jssora02l.jssora02lds { background-position: -3px -33px; opacity: .3; pointer-events: none; }
        .jssora02r.jssora02rds { background-position: -63px -33px; opacity: .3; pointer-events: none; }
    </style>
    <div id="jssor_1" style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px; overflow: hidden; visibility: hidden;">
           <!-- Loading Screen -->
        
        <div data-u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
            <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity: 0.7; position: absolute; display: block; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
            <div style="position:absolute;display:block;background:url('img/loading.gif') no-repeat center center;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
        </div>
        <div data-u="slides" style="cursor: default; position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px; overflow: hidden;">
<!--             <div data-p="112.50"> -->
            <div data-p="112.50">                
                <img data-u="image" src="img/002.jpg" />
                <div data-u="caption" data-t="7" style="position:absolute;top:-10px;left:30px;width:350px;height:30px;z-index:0;background-color:rgba(235,81,0,0.5);font-size:20px;color:#ffffff;line-height:30px;text-align:center;">Cartera 001</div>
            </div>

            <div data-p="112.50" style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="img/003.jpg" />
                <div data-u="caption" data-t="7" style="position:absolute;top:-10px;left:30px;width:350px;height:30px;z-index:0;background-color:rgba(235,81,0,0.5);font-size:20px;color:#ffffff;line-height:30px;text-align:center;">Cartera 002</div>
            </div>

            <div data-p="112.50" style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="img/004.jpg" />
                <div data-u="caption" data-t="7" style="position:absolute;top:-10px;left:30px;width:350px;height:30px;z-index:0;background-color:rgba(235,81,0,0.5);font-size:20px;color:#ffffff;line-height:30px;text-align:center;">Cartera 003</div>
            </div>

            <div data-p="112.50" style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="img/005.jpg" />
                <div data-u="caption" data-t="7" style="position:absolute;top:-10px;left:30px;width:350px;height:30px;z-index:0;background-color:rgba(235,81,0,0.5);font-size:20px;color:#ffffff;line-height:30px;text-align:center;">Cartera 004</div>
            </div>

            <div data-p="112.50" style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="img/006.jpg" />
                <div data-u="caption" data-t="7" style="position:absolute;top:-10px;left:30px;width:350px;height:30px;z-index:0;background-color:rgba(235,81,0,0.5);font-size:20px;color:#ffffff;line-height:30px;text-align:center;">Cartera 005</div>
            </div>

            <div data-p="112.50" style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="img/007.jpg" />
                <div data-u="caption" data-t="7" style="position:absolute;top:-10px;left:30px;width:350px;height:30px;z-index:0;background-color:rgba(235,81,0,0.5);font-size:20px;color:#ffffff;line-height:30px;text-align:center;">Cartera 006</div>
            </div>

            <div data-p="112.50" style="display: none;">                
                <img data-u="image" src="img/008.jpg" />
                <div data-u="caption" data-t="7" style="position:absolute;top:-10px;left:30px;width:350px;height:30px;z-index:0;background-color:rgba(235,81,0,0.5);font-size:20px;color:#ffffff;line-height:30px;text-align:center;">Cartera 007</div>
            </div>

        <!-- Bullet Navigator -->
        <div data-u="navigator" class="jssorb01" style="bottom:16px;right:16px;">
            <div data-u="prototype" style="width:12px;height:12px;"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Arrow Navigator -->
        <span data-u="arrowleft" class="jssora02l" style="top:0px;left:8px;width:55px;height:55px;" data-autocenter="2"></span>
        <span data-u="arrowright" class="jssora02r" style="top:0px;right:8px;width:55px;height:55px;" data-autocenter="2"></span>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">jssor_1_slider_init();</script>
    <!-- #endregion Jssor Slider End -->
    </div>
</div>
<h1 class="replacetitle title">Club de Dominó</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mi consejo... intenta hacer el slider con "Boostrap", te pego un enlace de un ejemplo de slider con Boostrap.

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp

Tambien te aconsejo que si tienes tiempo, actualizar la version de Cakephp. la version 1.X esta un poco antiguada y puede tener muchas brechas de seguridad. Si vas actualizar la version de Cakephp, Ten cuidado. Hay un salto abismal de la version 1.X a la version 3.X.

Comment: deberías agregar algo más, un link por si solo no me parece una buena respuesta